# Resolve cd : Cannot find path "pathname" because it does not exist. (When it does.)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, path

Everytime I run some code that I wrote in java on Visual-Studio-Code ,except from the first time , I get this error in the terminal  but it does not affect the program's execution . What is the issue here? I've tried  to access the files with cmd and I did it successfuly .
Here is the error that I get: https://prnt.sc/wmxor3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any differences after you open other working directory? How about running the project whose directory is all English and no space included?

Comment: I made another project whose directory is all English without space and the error does not appear! Is there any way that I can implement paths with the previous structure though?

Comment: The path in the failure message seems to contain `ΓΈπαλ` (or is it `Γ΄Επαλ`?), whereas the actual path seems to contain `ΓΕπαλ`, which is probably not the same path. Whatever creates that `cd ...` command has to pass the correct path.

Comment: @Vaggelis_kamp. I'm afraid it's hard to realize. Try to avoid using sapces and non-English character in path, which will cause this kind of error.